# Updating a table using Case statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to add a 0, 1, or null to a column in a specific category where a `relativepersonid` of a `person` has a `diagdate` up to a `person`'s `servicedate`. Here are my tables:

```
 DROP TABLE ICDCodes_w;
 GO
 CREATE TABLE ICDCodes_w
(
    AnxietyDisorder VARCHAR(6),
    DepressiveDisorder VARCHAR(6),
    PTSD VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO ICDCodes_w
(
    AnxietyDisorder,
    DepressiveDisorder,
    PTSD
)
VALUES
('293.84', '296.2', '309.81'),
('300', '296.21', 'F43.1'),
('305.42', 'F11.28', 'F31.76'),
('305.81', 'F43.8', 'F31.78'),
('F40.00', 'F43.10', '305.52');
GO
DROP TABLE DiagHX_w;
GO
CREATE TABLE DiagHX_w
(
    ArchiveID VARCHAR(10),
    RelativePersonID VARCHAR(10),
    ICDCode VARCHAR(6), 
    DiagDate DATE 
);

INSERT INTO DiagHX_w
(
    ArchiveID,
    RelativePersonID,
    ICDCode, 
    DiagDate
)
VALUES
('1275741', '754241', '293.84', '1989-01-03'),
('2154872', '754241', '293.84', '1995-04-07'),
('4587215', '754241', '998.4', '1999-12-07'),
('4588775', '711121', 'F11.28', '2001-02-07'),
('3545455', '711121', NULL, NULL),
('9876352', '323668', '400.02', '1988-04-09'),
('3211514', '112101', 'F31.78', '2005-09-09'),
('3254548', '686967', 'F40.00', '1999-12-31'),
('4411144', '686967', '305.52', '2000-01-01'),
('6548785', '99999999','F40.00', '2000-02-03');
GO
DROP TABLE PatientFlags_w;
GO
CREATE TABLE PatientFlags_w
(
    PersonID VARCHAR(10),
    RelativePersonID VARCHAR(10),
    AnxietyDisorder VARCHAR(2),
    DepressiveDisorder VARCHAR(2),
    PTSD VARCHAR(2),
);

INSERT INTO PatientFlags_w
(
    PersonID,
    RelativePersonID
)
VALUES
('99999999', '754241'),
('88888888', '754241'),
('77777777', '754241'),
('66666666', '711121'),
('55555555', '711121'),
('44444444', '323668'),
('33333333', '112101'),
('22222222', '686967'),
('11111111', '686967'),
('32151111', '887878'),
('78746954', '771125'),
('54621333', '333114'),
('55648888', '333114');
GO
DROP TABLE Person_w;
GO
CREATE TABLE Person_w
(
    PersonID VARCHAR(10),
    ServiceDate date
);

INSERT INTO Person_w
(
    PersonID,
    ServiceDate
)
VALUES
('99999999', '2000-12-31'),
('88888888', '2000-11-01'),
('69876541', '2000-09-04'),
('66666666', '2000-01-15'),
('55555555', '2000-07-22'),
('44444444', '2000-07-20'),
('65498711', '2000-11-17'),
('22222222', '2000-09-02'),
('11111111', '2000-02-04'),
('32151111', '2000-02-17'),
('78746954', '2000-03-29'),
('54621333', '2000-08-22'),
('55648888', '2000-10-20');
```

Here is my update statement:

```
UPDATE a
SET AnxietyDisorder = CASE
                      WHEN ICDCode IN
                           (
                               SELECT AnxietyDisorder FROM 
                               Project..ICDCodes_w
                           ) THEN
                          1
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END,
DepressiveDisorder = CASE
                         WHEN ICDCode IN
                              (
                                  SELECT DepressiveDisorder FROM 
                                  Project..ICDCodes_w
                              ) THEN
                             1
                         ELSE
                             0
                     END,
PTSD = CASE
           WHEN ICDCode IN
                (
                    SELECT PTSD FROM Project..ICDCodes_w
                ) THEN
               1
           ELSE
               0
       END
FROM PatientFlags_w a
JOIN DiagHX_w b
    ON a.relativepersonid = b.RelativePersonID
JOIN Person_w p 
ON a.personid = p.PersonID
WHERE diagdate <= p.servicedate;
```

This works on some values, but there are some that don't get updated. I know the issue is with my case statement and probably a join issue. What is a better way to write this? Here is an example query I used to check. The `PTSD` column should have a 1.

```
SELECT * FROM project..patientflags_w a 
JOIN project..diaghx_w b 
ON a.relativepersonid = b.RelativePersonID
JOIN project..person_w p 
ON a.personid = p.personid 
WHERE b.icdcode IN (SELECT PTSD FROM Project..ICDCodes_w) 
AND b.diagdate <= p.servicedate
```

I did ask this question the other day, but my sample tables were all messed up, so I've verified that they work this time.

Comment: "This works on some values, but there are some that don't get updated"  Ok, which ones does it work on, and which ones doesn't it?   When something doesn't get updated, what are you expecting to update and to what?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your query, at least the case statements, seem fine. If there is a matter of rows not updating, it has to do with the joins or the where. I notice some null values on diagdate; maybe you want isnull(diagdate,'19000101') instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the problem with your query is that you update the target (PatientFlags_w) multiple times: once for each flag. In some cases you seem to be ending up with the correct result, but its just by luck.

It's hard to tell if you want one row per person in the flag table, or one row per flag.

Can you review these queries and let us know if they are close to your desired results:

```
-- If you want one row per Person:
select  RelativePersonID, 
        [AnxietyDisorder] = max(case when c.AnxietyDisorder is not null then 1 else 0 end),
        [DepressiveDisorder] = max(case when c.DepressiveDisorder is not null then 1 else 0 end),
        [PTSD] = max(case when c.PTSD is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from    DiagHX_w d
left 
join    ICDCodes_w c on d.ICDCode in (c.AnxietyDisorder, c.DepressiveDisorder, c.PTSD)
group
by      RelativePersonID;


-- If you want one row per Flag:
select  RelativePersonID, 
        d.ICDCode,
        [AnxietyDisorder] = case when c.AnxietyDisorder is not null then 1 else 0 end,
        [DepressiveDisorder] = case when c.DepressiveDisorder is not null then 1 else 0 end,
        [PTSD] = case when c.PTSD is not null then 1 else 0 end
from    DiagHX_w d
left 
join    ICDCodes_w c on d.ICDCode in (c.AnxietyDisorder, c.DepressiveDisorder, c.PTSD);
```

If the diagnoses are not related to each other (I assumed since they are in the same table), you might want this instead:

```
select  RelativePersonID, 
        [AnxietyDisorder] = max(case when c.AnxietyDisorder = d.ICDCode then 1 else 0 end),
        [DepressiveDisorder] = max(case when c.DepressiveDisorder = d.ICDCode then 1 else 0 end),
        [PTSD] = max(case when c.PTSD = d.ICDCode then 1 else 0 end)
from    DiagHX_w d
left 
join    ICDCodes_w c on d.ICDCode in (c.AnxietyDisorder, c.DepressiveDisorder, c.PTSD)
group
by      RelativePersonID;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I just want a flag to be '1' if the relativepersonid had the diagnosis EVER, so I would just want one row per flag. The first query is closer to what I am wanting, but when I run it, it looks like i'm still getting false positives and vice versa.

Comment: The first query is one row per *person*. Help me zero in on a false positive in the first query.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. I just want one row per person. So if the person had all three diagnoses flagged as '1', I would just want one row.

Comment: SELECT a.relativepersonid, a.anxietydisorder, a.depressivedisorder, a.ptsd, b.icdcode
FROM Project..PatientFlags_w a
    JOIN Project..DiagHX_w b
        ON a.RelativePersonID = b.RelativePersonID
    JOIN Project..Person_w p
        ON a.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN Project..ICDCodes_w i
        ON b.ICDCode = i.PTSD; --only relativepersonid = 686967 should have PTSD = 1

Comment: I added a third query that might get us closer.  I had assumed the ICDcodes were related to each other

Comment: In the original test data 686967 has codes F40.00 & 305.52, so wouldnt we want Anxiety & PTSD flags enabled?

Comment: We would want Anxiety and PTSD flags for 686967, you are correct! Splitting the joins is actually perfect! THANK YOU. I have wasted an embarrassing amount of time on this

Comment: Great. I edited again to show a single join but with an equality check. Should be what you need